# Convert chrono duration to time_point

Tags: c++11, c++-chrono

How can I convert a chrono duration to a time_point, which is later than clock's epoch with the given duration? I tried to find epoch time in chrono clock without success.

Comment: By adding the duration to a base time point? There are [`operator+` overloads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/operator_arith2) available.

Comment: What is the base timepoint?

Comment: I see, time_point default constructor creates Clock's epoch time point.

Comment: If you want the epoch, then yes the default [`std::time_point` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/time_point) will create such a time point. There is also a [`std::time_point` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/time_point) that takes a duration and will add that duration to the epoch.

Comment: Even better. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the synopsis in 20.12.6 [time.point]:

```
template <class Clock, class Duration = typename Clock::duration>
class time_point
{
public:
    constexpr explicit time_point(const duration& d);  // same as time_point() + d
```

This can be used (for example) like:

```
using namespace std::chrono;
system_clock::time_point tp{30min}; // Needs C++14 for the literal
```

Though the system_clock::time_point is not specified in the standard, in practice this creates a `time_point` referring to 1970-01-01 00:30:00 UTC.